# VBA: if value found in reference sheet, then pull data + fields from source sheet into destination sheet

Tags: excel, vba, loops, reference

I have data in 2 sheets; a reference sheet with a list of Case ID's and a source sheet with Case ID's, client names, numbers, descriptions, etc.

The goal is to create a VBA loop that checks each row of the source sheet ***against*** the reference sheet and if the value is present in the **reference** sheet, pull in all required fields from the source sheet into the Destination sheet. My current VBA code is using an offset, but that doesn't seem to work correctly. Code below:

```
Public Sub MainFileData2()

Dim i As Long, k As Long

Dim wbmacro As Workbook
Dim wbmain As Workbook

Set wbmacro = Workbooks.Item("MacroFile.xlsm")
Set wbmain = Workbooks.Item("SourceFile.csv")

Dim wsmacro As Worksheet
Dim wsmain As Worksheet
Dim wsref As Worksheet

Set wsmacro = wbmacro.Worksheets.Item("Data")
Set wsmain = wbmain.Worksheets.Item("SourceFileData")
Set wsref = wbmacro.Worksheets.Item("Sheet1")
Set destsht = Workbooks("MacroFile.xlsm").Worksheets("Data")

Dim engrange As Range
Set engrange = wsmain.Range("B2:B500000")

Dim cell As Range

k = 1
i = 2
DestLastRow = destsht.Cells(destsht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each cell In engrange

    If engrange.Cells(i, 1) = wsref.Cells(k, 1) Then

        wsmacro.Range("candnum").Offset(i, 0) = wsmain.Range("b2").Offset(i, 0)
        wsmacro.Range("candname").Offset(i, 0) = wsmain.Range("c2").Offset(i, 0)
        wsmacro.Range("estat").Offset(i, 0) = wsmain.Range("e2").Offset(i, 0)
        wsmacro.Range("ira").Offset(i, 0) = wsmain.Range("g2").Offset(i, 0)
        wsmacro.Range("wrkflw").Offset(i, 0) = wsmain.Range("k2").Offset(i, 0)
        wsmacro.Range("fln").Offset(i, 0) = wsmain.Range("o2").Offset(i, 0)
        wsmacro.Range("city").Offset(i, 0) = wsmain.Range("r2").Offset(i, 0)
        wsmacro.Range("country").Offset(i, 0) = wsmain.Range("s2").Offset(i, 0)

        i = i + 1

        Else: i = i + 1


    End If

Next cell

Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

As the code cycles through `i`, it finds the value at row 20 in the Source File, for example and ends up pasting the values all the way into row 20 in the Destination File ("Data" sheet), skipping the first 19 blank rows. I tried using *destlastrow* instead of *i* and it ended up overwriting the value and didn't work correctly either.

Any ideas/input would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A couple of questions... 1. Can there only be up to one instance of each CaseID in the source and reference sheets? 2. Does this need to be done with VBA?  If the answer to my first question is yes, you could easily pull the data from the reference sheet using VLOOKUP or INDEX+MATCH, then just copy the data into a new workbook.   If a VBA solution is required, that's fine but your code will need some work.  Let me know what works for you.

Comment: @DavidN, unfortunately, VBA is required. There is another part to it which I've worked out, but the VBA is needed as of now. 

In the Reference sheet there would only be one instance of each. In the source sheet, there could be multiple rows that have the same Case ID, which is why I was trying to use the "IF x = y" type of code.

Comment: `If engrange.Cells(i, 1) = wsref.Cells(k, 1) Then` this line makes no sense - `engrange` is `Range("B2:B500000")` - what role does `cell` play in your loop? What role does column B play?? That really should be something like `If cell.Value = wsref.Cells(k, 1).Value Then`.

Comment: engrange is from the source data sheet. the Case ID's start in column b and i was simply trying to define it.

Comment: @VBAWARD Help me understand - so if a cell in column B equals the value in cell(2, 1) on Sheet1, what do you want to happen?

Comment: @dwirony: if the case id in the source data sheet (Column b; therefore scanning b2, b3, etc) matches, or is found in the reference sheet (Sheet1, column 1), then pull in all the fields stated above into the destination sheet. thats the goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite few major issues with your code.  Not trying to be harsh, but hopefully it will help you understand the changes I'm proposing.

You have two variables to use as indices (`i`,`k`), but you're only incrementing `i`.  `k` stays the same the whole time.  That's why you're only getting output in 1 row.

You've also used a `For Each` loop which essentially adds another set of invisible indices for the same data set you're using on `i`.  You're better off using a `For` loop with `i`, which will eliminate the need for `i=i+1`, and creating `enrange`.

Also, within the `IF` statement section of your code, you're using `i` on either side of the = sign, which is why you're getting your 1 result output on `wsmacro` in the same row that it's found on `wsmain`.

Using `DestLastRow` instead of `i` for your output row on `wsmacro` will give you issues as well because it's only calculated once (you don't have it within a loop) which is why the data is overwritten.

You've got 3 different sheets you're travelling down, so you need 3 different indices.

Also, `wsmacro` and `destsht` refer to the same worksheet.  You don't need both.

With all that said, here is my untested proposal:

```
Public Sub MainFileData2()

Dim iDest As Long, iMain As Long, iRef As Long
Dim MainLastRow As Long, RefLastRow As Long

Dim wbMacro As Workbook
Dim wbMain As Workbook

Set wbMacro = Workbooks.Item("MacroFile.xlsm")
Set wbMain = Workbooks.Item("SourceFile.csv")

Dim wsMacro As Worksheet
Dim wsMain As Worksheet
Dim wsRef As Worksheet

Set wsMain = wbMain.Worksheets.Item("SourceFileData")
Set wsRef = wbMacro.Worksheets.Item("Sheet1")
Set wsMacro = wbMacro.Worksheets("Data")

iMacro = 1   'Index for the destination sheet

MainLastRow = wsMain.Cells(wsMain.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
RefLastRow = wsRef.Cells(wsRef.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


For iMain = 2 To MainLastRow    'Go through each row of wsMain
    For iRef = 2 To RefLastRow  'For each row in the Main sheet, go through each row of the reference sheet
        If wsMain.Cells(iMain, 1) = wsRef.Cells(iRef, 1) Then

            wsMacro.Range("candnum").Offset(iMacro, 0) = wsMain.Cells(iMain, "B")
            wsMacro.Range("candname").Offset(iMacro, 0) = wsMain.Cells(iMain, "C")
            wsMacro.Range("estat").Offset(iMacro, 0) = wsMain.Cells(iMain, "E")
            wsMacro.Range("ira").Offset(iMacro, 0) = wsMain.Cells(iMain, "G")
            wsMacro.Range("wrkflw").Offset(iMacro, 0) = wsMain.Cells(iMain, "K")
            wsMacro.Range("fln").Offset(iMacro, 0) = wsMain.Cells(iMain, "O")
            wsMacro.Range("city").Offset(iMacro, 0) = wsMain.Cells(iMain, "R")
            wsMacro.Range("country").Offset(iMacro, 0) = wsMain.Cells(iMain, "S")

            iMacro = iMacro + 1 'Ensures the next output to wsMacro will go in the next row

            Exit For 'The match has been found, so you can move on to the next row in wsMain without checking the rest of the rows in wsRef
        End If
    Next iRef
Next iMain

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: this works great so far! the only one problem i'm having is that if the value repeats in the wsmain file, it doesnt pick up the 2nd row because of the EXIT FOR. any idea how to get it to cycle through and grab data if the data repeats in the next row?

Comment: i removed the EXIT FOR statement and it seems to work great! would this have any repercussions?

Comment: @VBAWARD, I'm glad it worked for you!  I'm surprised that the `Exit For` was giving that trouble.  Removing it shouldn't cause any issues.  It just means the code will take a little longer to run.  The intention of that code was that as soon as a match was found in wsRef, it would pull the data into wsMacro and immediately move on to the next iMain.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should really be structured more like this - use `i` only as the destination row counter, incrementing it only when you've added a line. Your `For each cell in engrange` will go through every cell in `Range("B2:B500000")` - don't try to use `engrange`again in your loop when you've already defined it as the range you're iterating through.

Although, I can only do so much here because I have no idea what those named ranges refer to - IMO, I'd get rid of the named ranges altogether.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub MainFileData2()

Dim i As Long, k As Long

Dim wbmacro As Workbook
Dim wbmain As Workbook

Set wbmacro = Workbooks.Item("MacroFile.xlsm")
Set wbmain = Workbooks.Item("SourceFile.csv")

Dim wsmacro As Worksheet
Dim wsmain As Worksheet
Dim wsref As Worksheet

Set wsmacro = wbmacro.Worksheets.Item("Data")
Set wsmain = wbmain.Worksheets.Item("SourceFileData")
Set wsref = wbmacro.Worksheets.Item("Sheet1")

Dim engrange As Range
Set engrange = wsmain.Range("B2:B500000")

Dim cell As Range

k = 1
i = 2

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each cell In engrange

    If cell.Value = wsref.Cells(k, 1).Value Then

        wsmacro.Cells(i, 1).Value = cell.Offset(, 1).Value
        wsmacro.Cells(i, 2).Value = cell.Offset(, 2).Value
        wsmacro.Cells(i, 3).Value = cell.Offset(, 3).Value
        wsmacro.Cells(i, 4).Value = cell.Offset(, 4).Value
        wsmacro.Cells(i, 5).Value = cell.Offset(, 5).Value
        wsmacro.Cells(i, 6).Value = cell.Offset(, 6).Value
        wsmacro.Cells(i, 7).Value = cell.Offset(, 7).Value
        wsmacro.Cells(i, 8).Value = cell.Offset(, 8).Value

        i = i + 1

    End If

Next cell

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the input. ive removed the name ranges and i'm trying to adjust the code to apply to my situation. however, there issue im running into thus far is that as it cycles through the source sheet, it is no longer checking against the reference sheet. how do i ensure its checking against it? as of now, it finds 1 match, runs and then stops. 

to clarify, it finds one match, copies the data, cycles through and copies the second row but even when it comes across a value that is found in the reference sheet (sheet1), it isn't recognizing it as a match and then the code stops.

Comment: Are you talking about your existing code or the new code that I've posted? There are several issues with your existing code - it is **not** going to do what you're expecting it to.

Answer (score 0):

A few things that might help

1. I would recommend changing `engrange` to a `Long` datatype and `Set engrange = wsmain.Range("B2:B500000")` to `engrange = wsmain.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` that way you can utilize a `For Loop` and you don't have to manually increment i every iteration.
2. I would try using an output range that is offset every iteration where your `If` statement evaluates to `True`. Right now it's just taking the `i` value and placing it there because you're increasing it every iteration.
3. It looks like you're trying to match a value. Instead of looping through the entire sheet for every value looking for a match, why not use .Find?

I would write it like this

```
Public Sub MainFileData2()

Dim i As Long, k As Long

Dim wbmacro As Workbook
Dim wbmain As Workbook

Set wbmacro = Workbooks.Item("MacroFile.xlsm")
Set wbmain = Workbooks.Item("SourceFile.csv")

Dim wsmacro As Worksheet
Dim wsmain As Worksheet
Dim wsref As Worksheet

Set wsmacro = wbmacro.Worksheets.Item("Data")
Set wsmain = wbmain.Worksheets.Item("SourceFileData")
Set wsref = wbmacro.Worksheets.Item("Sheet1")
Set destsht = Workbooks("MacroFile.xlsm").Worksheets("Data")

Dim engrange As Long
engrange = wsmain.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim fRng as Range

Dim outRng as Range
Set outRng = wsmacro.Range("A2")    

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For i = 2 to engrange

    Set fRng = wsref.Range("A:A").Find(wsmain.Cells(i, 2),,xlValues,xlWhole)

    If not fRng Is Nothing Then

        outRng.Offset(0, 0) = wsmain.Range("B" & i)
        outRng.Offset(0, 1) = wsmain.Range("C" & i)
        outRng.Offset(0, 2) = wsmain.Range("E" & i)
        outRng.Offset(0, 3) = wsmain.Range("G" & i)
        outRng.Offset(0, 4) = wsmain.Range("K" & i)
        outRng.Offset(0, 5) = wsmain.Range("O" & i)
        outRng.Offset(0, 6) = wsmain.Range("R" & i)
        outRng.Offset(0, 7) = wsmain.Range("S" & i)

        Set outRng = outRng.Offset(1, 0)

    End If

Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

A find function will perform alot faster than searching every cell for a match, and using the `Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` method will ensure you're never searching blank rows.

Comment: thanks for your input! i got an immediate error on the set outrng.offset (1,0)  portion. any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistype on my end, meant to put `Set outRng = outRng.Offset(1,0)`. I've edited it.

Comment: tried running this and it doesn't work. the outrng.offset seems to contain the column headings in the destination sheet, but it doesn't perform a match between the main sheet and the reference sheet and spit out any values. not sure what i should be altering?

Comment: `Set fRng = wsref.Range("A:A").Find(wsmain.Cells(i, 1),,xlValues,xlWhole)` Should be checking to see if exact value `wsmain.Cells(i,1)` exists in `wsref.Range("A:A")`. Have you tried stepping through it to see if `fRng` finds anything?

Comment: i have. fRng is simply "Nothing" - doesn't seem to find any values.

Comment: I think I may have figured it out. In your initial macro, when you defined `engrange` you set it equal to `Range("B2:B50000")`, meaining that `engrange.Cells(i,1)` actually refers to `Range("B" & i)` instead of `Range("A" & i)` like i was assuming. So I'm gonna ask this for clarification, which columns in wsref and wsmain are you trying to compare to the other?

Comment: wsref has data (Case ID's) in only column A. wsmain has the Case ID's which is being compared against wsref in column B.

Comment: That would explain why it wasn't finding anything. I've changed it now so that values from column B of wsmain are being searched for in values from column A in wsref.